# Maven not working on windows

Tags: java, maven

When I ran `mvn -v`, I didn't get the version.  I got the following

```
C:\>mvn -v
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    ......
```

I believe I set the path correct.  Here is the path

```
C:\>path
PATH=C:\java7\bin;C:\maven\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin

C:\>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\java7

C:\>java -version
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pwa6470sr8fp10-20141219_01(SR8 FP10))IBM J9 VM (build 2.6, JRE 1.7.0 Windows 7 amd64-64 Compressed References 20141216_227497 (JIT enablebled)
```

Any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: Have you added m2_home environment variable. Refer this, it explains the steps in detail:      http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/

Comment: Thanks. But still not working.

Comment: Now set both M2_HOME and MAVEN_HOME.                                                                                               C:\>set path=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin

C:\>set path
Path=C:\java7\bin;C:\maven\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC

Comment: still got the problem when I did mvn -v

Answer (score 0):

Set following environment variables. It works for me like a charm.

```
JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0

M2_HOME-    D:\java\apache-maven-3.1.0-bin\apache-maven-3.1.0

path-       C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;D:\java\apache-maven-3.1.0-bin\apache-maven-3.1.0\bin;

MAVEN_HOME -D:\java\apache-maven-3.1.0-bin\apache-maven-3.1.0
```

Check **mvn -v** in command prompt.

```
C:\>mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.1.0 (893ca28a1da9d5f51ac03827af98bb730128f9f2; 2013-06-28 07:45:32+0530)
Maven home: D:\java\apache-maven-3.1.0-bin\apache-maven-3.1.0
Java version: 1.7.0, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
C:\>
```

Answer (score 0):

on windows 10 you have type

```
mvn.cmd
```

in order to make it work correctly

Answer (score -1):

Add M2_HOME variable in the command prompt.

M2_HOME=C:\maven\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin
PATH=C:\java7\bin;%M2_HOME%